# Call StateHasChanged on sibling page

Tags: blazor

I have a page with an Order object declared as a CascadingValue.  That parent page has 2 child pages, one with order information and one with a list of line items on the order.  Each of these sibling pages uses the Order information via the CascadingValue.

There's a button on the order info page that should clear out all line items on the order.  The button works and all line items are cleared by calling the ClearLineItems method on the Order CascadingValue.

The page with the list of line items is not getting refreshed, though.  It still shows the line items that have now been deleted.  How can one page tell its sibling page that its StateHasChanged?

To paint the line items, i have a control called LineItemDetail and I paint it like this.  (There's a button on each line that allows the user to delete just that line, which is the DeleteLine parameter.  Deleting line by line is working correctly)

```
@foreach (var row in CurrentOrder.LineItems)
{
    <LineItemDetail CurrentLine=@row DeleteLine=@DelLine></UpchargeInfo>
}
```

Really the bigger question here is how to send messages from one Blazor page to another.  Like a message bus but internal to Blazor.

This demonstrates the problem.  Adding a line item from child forms does not update the parent form, nor the other sibling.  One must actively refresh the parent, which will cascade down and update children.
https://github.com/bradirby/BlazorChildFormUpdates

Comment: Hi Brad, Server side or WebAssembly? Clarifying Pages not components right?

Comment: This is web assembly

Comment: I got this working with events (see github link above), but it's not a robust solution.  If one has forms that are several levels deep, passing the callback references would become difficult quickly.  If anyone has a better solution, please post.

Answer (score 0):

My original answer seems outdated; except for the part that using EventCallbacks could be a solution.

So here is my new answer:

Add References to the component. Something like this:

```
<Component1 @ref="comp1" SiblingComponent="@comp2" />
<Component2 @ref="comp2" SiblingComponent="@comp1" />

@code {
    public ElementReference comp1 { get; set; }
    public ElementReference comp2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then inside the Component1 ans Component2 you call `SiblingComponent.UpdateState()`

and the SiblingComponent then inplements

```
private void UpdateState() {
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Aparently oudated answer:

*Most likely the problem is not that the StateChanged is not called, the problem is that in fact the state hasn't changed for the sibling page.
You cannot change a cascading value in a child component. It will only be changed for the copy in that child component, not in the parent component.
You have some options; but the most fitting one is likely a callback method. Your action on the child component triggers a method in the parent component which changes the value on the parent level, which updates the value in the child components.*

Comment: That's not how Blazor works.  CascadingValues are pass by reference, not by value.  Updating an object in a child form will succeed, but you won't see the changes in the parent until it is refreshed.  I edited the original post to include a test project.

Comment: I assumed the value is passed since I assumed you cannot update the Cascading value in a child component. That is based on the information I got here: https://chrissainty.com/understanding-cascading-values-and-cascading-parameters/
-----
"There has been a bit of confusion when it comes to updating cascading values. The important thing to understand is that updates only cascade down you can't update a value from a descendant."

Comment: I suspect that post is outdated. It's from Feb 2019 and Blazor is changing quickly.

Comment: Passing a reference to siblings would be problematic.  In the app I'm working on i have 8 sibling forms under the parent, and several of those have children of their own.  Also, forms should only be aware of their parent and children, not siblings or distant relatives.  In the solution I posted to github above i used callbacks to the parent.  Refreshing the parent will also refresh all the children so it works well.

Comment: Yeah if you have a list of siblings my original answer would be the way to go. You could work with a list of ElementReferences if you had to. These you can store in your parent, but that would still require an EventCallback anyway. So it would be kinda useless to do it that way/